# .NET Core 2.0 Autofac Register Class InstancePerRequest doesn't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

Here is my  interface

```
public interface IMatchServices
{
    string MatchList();
}
```

and class here

```
public class MatchServices : IMatchServices
{
    public string MatchList() {

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMatchServices matchservices;

    public SearchController(IMatchServices matchservices)
    {
        this.matchservices = matchservices;
    }

    [Route("matchlist")]
    public string MatchList() {

        return matchservices.MatchList();
    }
}
```

and `ConfigureService`

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MatchServices>().As<IMatchServices>().SingleInstance();
    builder.Populate(services);
    var container = builder.Build();
    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

And Finally The Error (When I register with `InstancePerRequest`):

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type
>   'xxx.Services.MatchServices' because the lifetime scope it belongs in
>   can't be located. The following services are exposed by this
>   registration:
>   - xxx.Interfaces.IMatchServices
>
> Details ---> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is
>   visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
>
> If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally
>   indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being
>   requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario).
>   Under the web integration always request dependencies from the
>   dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the
>   container itself. (See inner exception for details.) --->
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a tag
>   matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the
>   instance was requested.

When I register MatchServices class `SingleInstance` it is working but `InstancePerRequest` didn't work. Why? I didn't even do any DI in `MatchServices`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per the [Autofac documentation](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#differences-from-asp-net-classic):

> **Use InstancePerLifetimeScope instead of InstancePerRequest**. In previous ASP.NET integration you could register a dependency as `InstancePerRequest` which would ensure only one instance of the dependency would be created per HTTP request. This worked because Autofac was in charge of setting up the per-request lifetime scope. With the introduction of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, the creation of per-request and other child lifetime scopes is now part of the conforming container provided by the framework, so all child lifetime scopes are treated equally - there’s no special “request level scope” anymore. Instead of registering your dependencies `InstancePerRequest`, use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and you should get the same behavior. Note if you are creating your own lifetime scopes during web requests, you will get a new instance in these child scopes.

Also, you have [another issue](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-without-configurecontainer):

> Note that `Populate` is basically a foreach to add things
>     into Autofac that are in the collection. If you register
>     things in Autofac BEFORE `Populate` then the stuff in the
>     `ServiceCollection` can override those things; if you register
>     AFTER `Populate` those registrations can override things
>     in the `ServiceCollection`. Mix and match as needed.

In other words, you also have these lines in the wrong order:

```
builder.Populate(services);
builder.RegisterType<MatchServices>().As<IMatchServices>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: thanks  this fix the problem.. Using InstancePerLifetimeScope instead of InstancePerRequest.